# Is it possible external users to access Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have external/guew users(with personal Microsoft accounts) who have assigned o365 licenses. But they cannot access the graph Api. Should we assign some permissions and how?

Answer (score 0):

Due to you have external/guest users, you cannot use the latest Graph API but can use the [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet). Azure AD Graph API is not the same as Graph API now, you can learn more about the gaps between AAD and Microsoft Graph API: [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).

> You must use the Azure AD Graph API to manage users in an Azure AD B2C
>   directory. This is different from the Microsoft Graph API. Learn more
>   here.

Comment: Using the AAD Graph Explorer I could not Login with an external/guest account.

Comment: Not all feature can be tested by the Graph Explorer. Some feature need to be test by code. Of course, the result maybe bad: not support after testing. You can create an project follow by the Get Started of Graph official site and then change the appdi/secreykey or just create an console project by your self.